# Avoid duplicate element in foreach

Tags: php

I would like the code below to display only one time each $row[2] element (no duplicates) :

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo " {$row[2]} ";
}
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

My array is very big but here is a sample from `var_dump`

```
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=> string(2) "39"
    ["id"]=> string(2) "39"
    [1]=> string(3) "abc"
    ["A"]=> string(3) "abc"
    [2]=> string(2) "123"
    ["B"]=> string(2) "123"
    [3]=> string(1) "0"
    ["C"]=> string(1) "0"
    [4]=> string(1) "1"
    ["D"]=> string(1) "1"
  }
```

I'm only interested about `[2]=> string(2) "123"`.

Comment: Describe properly what do you want, and provide var_dump of $rows.

Comment: Please show the array `$rows` first. Try `print_r($rows)`

Comment: added var_dump output

Comment: You can get the `2` column from all subArrays with `array_column()` after that just use `array_unique()` on it to get the unique values.

Comment: And what does this code displays now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you can use:

```
$uniqueArr = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
        if(!(in_array($row[2], $uniqueArr))) {
                echo $row[2];
                $uniqueArr[] = $row[2];
        }
}
```